# How to beat the Twinscythe?

Tags: final-fantasy-brave-exvius

I need to complete the exploration quest [Windy Heights West - Exploration](https://exviuswiki.com/Windy_Heights_West/Exploration) but the boss of this area is a [Twinscythe](https://exviuswiki.com/Twinscythe) which, when I face it, kills two of my team each turn, using it's Drainsickle attack. So after three turns, it's Game Over.

What techniques or materias can I used to win this battle and clear this exploration quest?

Comment: buy IAP for stronger weapon and armor

Comment: What is "IAP" ?

Comment: in app purchase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things you can do to give yourself a better chance at passing this quest.

First, it might help if you had a tank character in your party, especially if they have draw attacks (or even better, provoke, which can be learned by Golem). Add in a couple of extra buffs to lower his attack (full break or power break) and buff your defenses (cheer) for extra survivability. With any luck, your tank can sustain a few hits.

Next, it'd probably be beneficial to have a character that can inflict some status effects. Twinscythe is susceptible to a couple of status effects that are pretty common and can greatly lower or eliminate incoming damage (blind and paralysis, respectively). If these status effects are applied strategically (apply one right as the other is about to end), you may not even need a tank, as you might be able to simply avoid all damage. The application and timing of good status effects is a bit random, so relying on this may take a few tries until it lands just right.

Finally, figure out your best course of action for dealing damage with the characters you have available. As he is weak to fire, bringing in a couple mages may be helpful. Getting elemental links on firagas can bring his health down pretty quick. Also, he is susceptible to poison, which is great because it does a percentage of damage (10% of max health) per turn. Bio Blaster is a relatively easy ability to create, and currently boasts the highest success rate of poison being applied (50%) in the game.

Comment: Do things like `Protect`, `Shell` or Elemental 'bar' spells diminish the damage of Drainsickle?

Comment: @DavidYell Protect does. Drainscythe is physical damage. That's the reason I suggested using Cheer, as that's one of the best defense-boosting moves in the game (at 40% to all units, Protect is only a single-unit for 30%), and also boosts your attack at the same time. You should have a unit with cheer, as long as you leveled Fina.

Comment: I have Cloud of Darkness with Protectga as well as Fina. Not sure if they stack.

Comment: @DavidYell buffs and debuffs do not stack, unfortunately. They will just keep the stronger one. That being said, Protectga also has 40% raise in defense, so it gives the same as Cheer, minus the atk gain.

Comment: @DavidYell I imagine you're past this by now, but if you're still playing, here's a great resource for any future difficulties: http://exvius.gamepedia.com/Twinscythe

Comment: @DCShannon Actually, no, not yet. I've been grinding events instead, should give it another go, now I have some 6* units.

Comment: @DavidYell Yeah, it's really not that bad. Max level 5-stars shouldn't have any trouble clearing that Twinscythe. If you have some decently high level 6-stars you should be gold.